Does traefik support TLS on both sides of the proxy_
Is there a way to configure Traefik to use TLS on both sides of the proxy?
In the internal side, I have an elasticsearch cluster with three nodes in different locations. The cluster has TLS enabled for all communications using internal certs. It is not directly exposed. All services are accesses via Traefik.
The whole thing is deployed using docker Swarm.
I am using letsencrypt on the external side. But on the internal side, I need Traefik to use the internal certs and CA. Is this possible?
